# C#- Maintain State of Checkbox and textbox in gridview on page changing

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, checkbox, webforms

I have a gridview having a textbox and a checkbox.when the checkbox is checked,a value will be populated into the textbox which a user may alter the value.

Here is the code for the gridview

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvPayment" runat ="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="Vertical" Width="100%" ShowFooter="true" CssClass="jumbSize1" OnRowDataBound="gvPayment_RowDataBound" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="5" OnPageIndexChanging="gvPayment_PageIndexChanging" >
<Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-Width="5%">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSelect" runat="server" CssClass="checkbox" OnCheckedChanged="chkSelect_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="true" />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="TRANSACTION DATE" HeaderStyle-Width="15%">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="SalesDate" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Date", "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}") %>' />
        </ItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate>
            <asp:Button ID="Submit" Text="Submit" runat="server" OnClick="Submit_Click" CssClass="btn btn-primary" />
        </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Sales Code" HeaderStyle-Width="15%">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="SalesCode" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("SALES_CODE") %>' />
        </ItemTemplate>
         <FooterTemplate>
        <div style="padding: 0 0 5px 0;">
            <asp:Label Text="Page Totals" runat="server" align="right" />
        </div>
         <div>
            <asp:Label Text="Grand Totals" runat="server" align="right" />
        </div>
    </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ACTUAL SALE" HeaderStyle-Width="15%">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="ActualSales" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("ACTUAL", "{0:N2}") %>' />
        </ItemTemplate>
         <FooterTemplate>
        <div style="padding: 0 0 5px 0;">
            <asp:Label ID="PageActual" runat="server" align="right" />
        </div>
         <div>
            <asp:Label ID="GrandActual" runat="server" align="right" />
        </div>
    </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ADVANCE" HeaderStyle-Width="15%">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="AdvPay" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("ADVANCE", "{0:N2}") %>' />
        </ItemTemplate>
         <FooterTemplate>
        <div style="padding: 0 0 5px 0;">
            <asp:Label ID="PageAdvance" runat="server" align="left" />
        </div>
         <div>
            <asp:Label ID="GrandAdvance" runat="server" align="left" />
        </div>
    </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="AMOUNT DUE" HeaderStyle-Width="15%">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="AmtDue" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("DUE", "{0:N2}") %>' />
        </ItemTemplate>
         <FooterTemplate>
        <div style="padding: 0 0 5px 0;">
            <asp:Label ID="PageDue" runat="server" align="left" />
        </div>
         <div>
            <asp:Label ID="GrandDue" runat="server" align="left" />
        </div>
    </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="AMOUNT PAID" HeaderStyle-Width="15%">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="AmtPaid" runat="server" CssClass="form-control CapLock" />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
<AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#4870BE" ForeColor="#FFFFFF" />
<FooterStyle BackColor="#76543c" ForeColor="#FFFFFF" Font-Bold="true" />
<HeaderStyle BackColor="#76543c" ForeColor="#FFFFFF" Font-Bold="true" />
<PagerSettings Mode="NextPrevious" NextPageText="Next &amp;gt;&amp;gt;" PreviousPageText="Prev &amp;lt;&amp;lt;" />
<PagerStyle BackColor="#76543c" ForeColor="#FFFFFF" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
<RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" /></asp:Gridview>
```

Here is the code to bind gridview to data source and get the grand totals in viewstate

```
private void GetCustomer()
{
    dt = new DataTable();
    try
    {
        using (con = new SqlConnection(conString))
        {
            using (cmd = con.CreateCommand())
            {
                string query = @"dbo.sp_get_sales";
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.CommandText = query;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", CustInfo.SelectedValue);
                con.Open();

                da = new SqlDataAdapter();
                da.SelectCommand = cmd;
                da.Fill(dt);

                //CALCULATE THE TOTAL AMOUNTS AND HOLD THE VALUE IN A "VIEWSTATE"
                ViewState["TotalActual"] = null;
                if (ViewState["TotalActual"] == null)
                {
                    Decimal dActual = 0;
                    for (int i = 0; i <= dt.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
                    {
                        dActual += dt.Rows[i].Field<Decimal>("ACTUAL");
                    }
                    ViewState["TotalActual"] = dActual.ToString("N2");
                }

                ViewState["TotalAdvance"] = null;
                if (ViewState["TotalAdvance"] == null)
                {
                    Decimal dAdvance = 0;
                    for (int i = 0; i <= dt.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
                    {
                        dAdvance += dt.Rows[i].Field<Decimal>("ADVANCE");
                    }
                    ViewState["TotalAdvance"] = dAdvance.ToString("N2");
                }

                ViewState["TotalDue"] = null;
                if (ViewState["TotalDue"] == null)
                {
                    Decimal dDue = 0;
                    for (int i = 0; i <= dt.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
                    {
                        dDue += dt.Rows[i].Field<Decimal>("DUE");
                    }
                    ViewState["TotalDue"] = dDue.ToString("N2");
                }
            }
            //BIND QUERY RESULT WITH THE GRIDVIEW
            gvPayment.DataSource = dt;
            gvPayment.DataBind();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ErrorMessage.Text = "An error occured: " + ex.Message;
    }
    finally
    {
        con.Close();
        con.Dispose();
    }

    foreach (GridViewRow row in gvPayment.Rows)
    {
        if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            TextBox AmtPaid = (TextBox)row.FindControl("AmtPaid");
            AmtPaid.Attributes.Add("readonly", "readonly");
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the code to enable and populate textbox on check changed event

```
protected void chkSelect_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow row = ((GridViewRow)((CheckBox)sender).NamingContainer);
    int index = row.RowIndex;
    CheckBox chkSelect = (CheckBox)gvPayment.Rows[index].FindControl("chkSelect");
    TextBox AmtPaid = (TextBox)gvPayment.Rows[index].FindControl("AmtPaid");
    Label AmtDue = (Label)gvPayment.Rows[index].FindControl("AmtDue");

    if (chkSelect.Checked && chkSelect != null)
    {
        AmtPaid.Text = AmtDue.Text.Replace(",", "");
        AmtPaid.Attributes.Remove("readonly");
    }
    else
    {
        AmtPaid.Text = string.Empty;
        AmtPaid.Attributes.Add("readonly", "readonly");
    }
}
```

The textbox get populated with the desired value when the checkbox is selected but both controls lost their values on pageindexchanging event.

I want the checkbox to maintain its state and textbox to maintain whatever value user entered when the pageindexchanging event is called.

Here is the code to move to next page

```
protected void gvPayment_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    gvPayment.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    GetCustomer();
}
```

Note: I have gone through all suggested similar questions with no luck or success.

Comment: I dont understand what happens. You say they lose their values on postback, where you check if they lost them? In `chkSelect_CheckedChanged` you are modifying the `AmtPaid.Text`. When it is changed? Are you calling `GetCustomer` only `if(!IsPostBack)` or always?

Comment: I have modified my question. On page load I use d if(!IsPostBack) but onpaging i just use GetCustomer()

Comment: You have to persist them yourself. I will try to write an answer. But note that here is a bug: `chkSelect.Checked && chkSelect != null`. If it's null you will get an exception because you first check chkSelect.Checked .

Comment: Also, if you use the `using`-statement you don't need `con.Close` and `con.Dispose`.

Comment: I will be grateful if you do. Help me to also correct the bug you identified in your answer.

Comment: What identifies a sale/transaction? You have an ID or something like that(unique number)?

Comment: SalesCode identifies a transaction but it is not unique. A sales receipt can have multiple items sold in a single transaction. Do you want me to post my db code?

Comment: No, but you need a way to persist the selection of the CheckBoxes temporarily. Therefore you need a key to identify them. You could use the page+index but that would be prone of errors if the order could change later. What is the key if you update a record(the sales receipt)?

Comment: The unique key is ID. It is an identity column but the values on the gridview are aggregated. Such as sum of amount sold less sum of amount paid. If you I add the Id to my db query, it won't return single row for a salescode.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162974/discussion-between-tim-schmelter-and-donsonde).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to persist them, for example by storing a `Disctionary<int, bool>` in the `ViewState` where the key is the `RowIndex` and the value is the `bool`(`CheckBox` is `Checked`?):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        ViewState["EnabledAmtPaidTextBoxes"] = new Dictionary<int, bool>();
        GetCustomer();
    }
}
```

I would encapsulate this logic in  a method, you need to call it from `RowDataBound` and `CheckedChanged`. You don't need that final loop in `GetCustomer` anymore:

```
protected void gvPayment_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        EnabledAmtPaidTextBox(e.Row);
    }
}

protected void chkSelect_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox chkSelect = (CheckBox)sender;
    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)chkSelect.NamingContainer;
    EnabledAmtPaidTextBox(row, chkSelect.Checked);
}

private void EnabledAmtPaidTextBox(GridViewRow row, bool? newCheckedOrApplyOld = null)
{
    TextBox AmtPaid = (TextBox)row.FindControl("AmtPaid");
    Label AmtDue = (Label)row.FindControl("AmtDue");
    CheckBox chkSelect = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("chkSelect");

    Dictionary<int, bool> enabledAmtPaidTextBoxes = (Dictionary<int, bool>)ViewState["EnabledAmtPaidTextBoxes"];
    if (!enabledAmtPaidTextBoxes.ContainsKey(row.RowIndex))
        enabledAmtPaidTextBoxes[row.RowIndex] = false;

    if (newCheckedOrApplyOld.HasValue)
        enabledAmtPaidTextBoxes[row.RowIndex] = newCheckedOrApplyOld.Value;
    else 
        chkSelect.Checked = enabledAmtPaidTextBoxes[row.RowIndex];

    if (enabledAmtPaidTextBoxes[row.RowIndex])
    {
        AmtPaid.Text = AmtDue.Text.Replace(",", "");
        AmtPaid.Attributes.Remove("readonly");
    }
    else
    {
        AmtPaid.Text = string.Empty;
        AmtPaid.Attributes.Add("readonly", "readonly");
    }
}
```

Also, if you use the using-statement you don't need `con.Close` and `con.Dispose` in `finally` because that is done by the `using`-statement already.

Comment: Thank you Tim. Let me apply your answer and give you feedback.

Comment: I tried the codes. The values of the textboxes persisted but the check state of the checkbox is unchecked. Secondly, it seems your code doesn't take note of page changes because if first row of page one is selected, all first row of all other subsequent pages has their textbox enabled with values. Please advise.

Comment: @donsonde: i have [edited](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48207019/revisions) my answer

Comment: Thank you @Tim for your patience. You are the best. It is working like charm. I only made one change to it. Where you have row.RowIndex , i changed it to row.RowIndex + gvPayment.PageIndex * gvPayment. PageSize to cater for unique rows in each page. Thank you again

Comment: Hello @Tim,  sorry  for troubling you again. This works only when AmtPaid is same as AmtDue. But when you alter the value in AmtPaid and click on next then click on previous, the value in AmtPaid changes to be same as AmtDue instead of the previously specified amount which is not equals to AmtDue.